# Find the Root in a given Graph?

Tags: data-structures, graph

Given a directed graph, Find the root of the graph i.e node with max outgoing node .

So that the graph can be divided into maximum individual sub trees.

Comment: These are two different things: the node with max outdeg doesn't have to be the one that gives you maximal number of subgraphs after it's deleted. What's more, if you just get a directed graph, you have no guarantee that you will get trees after you delete some node. Could clarify your problem? Do you get a tree, a DAG or just a directed graph? Do you want maximal outdeg our maximal number of subgraphs after you delete a node?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the graph is given as an Adjacency Matrix, you can scan each row to count the outgoing edges from corresponding node, and finally scan those values for each node to get the node with maximum outdegree. This will take O(n^2) time.

Comment: root. not degree.

Comment: Isn't root = node with max out degree according to the question?

Answer (score -1):

Scan the graph one by one and store number of outgoing edges in a sorted list and then the max number matches the root node